# Angular 4 - component selector not matching tags with attribute bindings

Tags: angular, angular5

FooComponent decorator:

```
@Component({selector: 'div[myAttr=foo]', ...)
```

AppComponent template:

```
<div [myAttr]="'foo'"></div>
<div myAttr="{{'foo'}}"></div>
```

The problem is that at runtime the FooComponent selector does not match the bound `<div>` attributes and we get left with empty divs in the DOM.

(Of course, it works if the template is `<div myAttr="foo"></div>` because it's a plain-old attribute.)

It would be really nice for this work so that different components can match against a dynamic value for myAttr. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I'm on `@angular/core@5.0.1`.